# JqueryUI autocomplete remove results minLength

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a problem with jqueryui autocomplete.
I print out the results of the autocomplete in another div like this

```
        $(function () {
            var ac = $("#search").autocomplete({
                source: "myurl",
                search: function (event, ui) {
                    // clear the existing result set
                    $('#results').empty();
                },
                minLength: 3
            });
            ac.data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $('<div class="col-md-2">' +
                        '<div class="thumbail">' +
                        '<a href="#"></a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>')
                        .appendTo($('#results'));
            };
        });
```

This works great when I search for something with over 2 characters. But if I press backspace and erase one character, making the query less than minLength, the search method is not called anymore, meaning that the previous results stay in my results div. Is there a way to clear the results when the query is shorter than minLength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding an event handler like:

```js
$("#search").on('input', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length >= 3) return;
  $('#results').empty();
});
```